# I am trying this code in Java but the result output is not clear to me. can someone please explain the reason for below output

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Below is the code I'm trying to run. If I remove the parameters from func() methods than the obj.func() call B class method but if I introduce the parameters it calls A class method.

```
public class A {
     void func(A obj) {
        System.out.println("in A");
      }
}

public class B extends A{
    void func(B obj) {
      System.out.println("in B");
    }
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new B();
    obj.func(null);// calls A class method, but why???
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are trying to **override** method *func* of class A in class B. Anyway, your code is **overloading** the method, because the type of the parameters of *A.func* and of *B.func* are different. The former receives an object *obj* of type **A**, while the second receives an object *obj* of type **B**.

```
public class A {
    void func(A obj) {
        System.out.println("in A");
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    void func(B obj) { // your solution, which creates a DIFFERENT method using overloading
        System.out.println("OVERLOAD in B");
    }
    void func(A obj) { // proper override of *A.func(A obj)*
        System.out.println("OVERRIDE in B");
    }
} // <- pay attention, you forgot this bracket
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new B();
    obj.func(null);// now it calls the right method
}}
```

If you remove the parameter of *func*, the two functions are identical, hence you have a proper override. That is why removing the argument the code worked properly.

I hope I was able to help you, anyway you can find more information here:

- Method overloading, that is what your previous code was doing: https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overloading-in-java
- Method overriding, that was your target: https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java
- Runtime polymorphism, that is what happens when you write *A obj = new B()*; https://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java

Have a good day!